# Expand array of string in druid

Tags: druid, apache-superset

I have a druid datasource which has a column of type varchar (string array). I want to get values from that column with their count using druid query. I am explaining my question with an example.

For Example:

```
-------------
|Column     |
-------------
|A          |
-------------
|[A,B,C]    |
-------------
|[B,C,D]    |
-------------
```

I want output to be like

```
-----------------------
|Name       | Count   |
-----------------------
|A          |1        |
-----------------------
|B          |2        |
-----------------------
|C          |2        |
-----------------------
|D          |1        |
-----------------------
```

Answer (score 0):

If you ingest as a multivalued dimension, you should be able to use a groupBy query to do this.  https://druid.apache.org/docs/latest/querying/multi-value-dimensions.html